# what is JSON REST interface

Tags: java, json, rest, servlets, java-server

Is there any tutorial on **JSON RESTful interface** (using **JAVA servlet**) ? The purpose is to call to external REST interface for data, and handle the data by the client(javascript client).

I am not sure what kind of thing is exactly JSON REST interface in JAVA... I need some tutorials to start to learn, so...I ask here.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[JSON](http://www.json.org/) is a light-weight data serialization format based on a subset of JavaScript.

A RESTful interface is one that conforms to the constraints and characteristics of the [REST architectural style](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm).

So, combining the two, a JSON RESTful interface is one that follows the REST architectural style and uses JSON as its data representation format (typically the content type `application/json`).

To implement a service of this kind in Java there are frameworks that can help you, such as [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) or [RESTEasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy). Both offer additional components that support JSON (for both incoming and outgoing data).

### EDIT:

Both Jersey and RESTEasy implement the JAX-RS spec, so it's possible to use either as a 'pure' Java EE way of doing things. If you want to use only the *Servlet* part of Java EE to do this, it's possible but you'll have to do things like parsing path/template parameters from the URI yourself.

You may find it difficult to use `servlet-mapping` elements to describe your resource URLs, and this might result in you implementing something that looks very much like JAX-RS (if you end up with one controller servlet that parses the URI and dispatches the request to another object).

I'd suggest reading a lot more on REST before you decide how to implement this. Here's some pointers:

- Communication between client and server should be **stateless**. Avoid the `HttpSession`.
- REST is resource-centric, not operation-centric (like RPC). Think of the resources that your service exposes and give these URIs.
- REST resources are manipulated through a common interface. For HTTP services, this interface is defined by the HTTP verbs (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc). Make sure you read [section 9 of RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9) to understand the semantics of each verb and the rules around what they should and should not do.
- Study the [response status codes and reason phrases in RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html#sec6.1.1). These are part of your common interface.
- RESTful services return *representations* of resources. A representation has a content type, make sure you set this header so that clients can understand your response.

Finally, if you go the 'pure Servlets' route, you may still find reading/creating JSON a lot easier using a parser library like [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/).

Comment: What if I want use pure servlet...how to implement this JSON REST interface? Any tutorial on this?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have any tutorial links to hand - I have updated my answer with some more info. I would certainly recommend using a JAX-RS implementation if you can.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response! I will take a look at JAX-RS. Regards!